# Office add-in: wide image on excel ribbon

Tags: c#, excel, image, visual-studio, ribbon

I just want to know if it is possible to put a wide image (for example 100px wide) on excel ribbon. Now for me the only possibility to put an image on ribbon is to make the image a big-size button but it's still only 32x32 px. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

The Fluent UI is described in depth in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, btw it's office 2013, my fault I didn't write it before.

Comment: It doesn't matter what Office version you are using at the moment. The Fluent UI wasn't changed since 2007.